# How are soft link inode value's determined?

Tags: unix, filesystems

In typical UNIX file systems, data and directory information are
both stored in structures called inodes. Figure 1 shows how a file
in directory/folder A named TheMatrix.jpg is stored starting at
inode 34119, where a set of file information and a list of locations
of its actual data are given. The first block containing actual data
is at inode 213456.
A second file called Link2Matrix.jpg in directory/folder B is linked to
the same file data. Indicate what would be the value of inode X
(shown inside the directory B block at the bottom left) when this
file is; (i) Hard linked to TheMatrix.jpg(ii) Symbolically (or soft linked) to TheMatrix.jpg

[Block diagram of inode based file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU28I.png)

I understand that hard linking a file results in inode X taking on the same value as the linked i.e. 34119

However my understanding is that a soft-link will result in a new inode value being generated. However, I do not know how this value is assigned and it appears to be quite arbitrary. Is there a clue in the diagram somewhere that indicates what inode X would be if a soft link was created?

TIA!